# What difference between libwxbase-xxx-dev and libwxgtk-xxx-dev?

Tags: gtk, wxwidgets

I am working on a GUI application which aims to be portable between different window managers(Gnome and KDE) and platforms(Linux and Windows).
Most of my work is done with C++ / wxWidgets.
I am currently preparing a new development environment.
I find several packages when searching "wx-config":

> myusername@domain:~$ wx-config --version
>   The program 'wx-config' can be found in the following packages:
>    * libwxbase2.8-dbg
>    * libwxbase2.8-dev
>    * libwxbase3.0-dev
>    * libwxgtk2.8-dbg
>    * libwxgtk2.8-dev
>    * libwxgtk3.0-dev
>   Try: sudo apt-get install

Could anyone explain to me what is the difference between **libwxbase-dev** and **libwxgtk-dev**?
I already know that a package is included in the other, but I need some more detailed information.

Thanks

IT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**libwxbase-dev:** wxBase library (development) - non-GUI support classes of wxWidgets toolkit

**libwxgtk-dev:** wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK+ development)

The second is focused purely on the GUI, using the first.

The first contains basic functionalities of the wxWidgets toolkit, non-gui oriented.

Comment: Thank for your time and response, @Mik378.
By working with C++11+wxWidgets, I need to support both Gtk and KDE.
According to the documentation, libwxgtk-xxx-dev is "wm-independent", so my wxWidgets/Gtk applications will should run fine on KDE also(I hope).

Comment: I've never used it, but if the documentation explicitly specifies it, the whole should be fine.

Comment: This post may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164204/gui-for-kde-and-gnome  Talks about the cross-platform feature of wxWidgets.

Comment: @IT. You may validate the answer if it satisfied you. That would remove it from the list of new questions.